# PHP merging arrays without overwriting data

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have a number of arrays, and I wish to merge them without overwriting or losing any data. I believe they are called associative arrays but I am not 100% sure about the terminology .

The arrays contain information like this:

```
$array1['title']
$array1['description']

$array2['title']
$array2['description']
$array2['random information']
```

I want to merge the information contained within the common keys of $array1 and $array2 without overwriting any data.

Is this possible?

Things I have tried, that were not successful, include the following:

```
(array)$array3 = (array)$array1 + array($array2);

$array3 = array_push($array1,$array2);

 $array3 = array_merge_recursive($array1,$array2);
```

Essentially I want to retain the common keys, and add the information from both arrays into the new array. For example, I only want one `['title'] ['description']` etc in the new array but I want the information from both arrays in the new array.

So $array3 will contain all the information that was in $array1 and $array2... all the items from `['title'] ['description']` will be retained under `['title'] ['description']` in $array3.

Is this possible?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Check out http://php.net/array_merge

Comment: What do you want to happen with the common keys in the two arrays?

Comment: @Schleis I want to retain the common keys, and add the information from both arrays into the new array. Thanks

Comment: @Schleis I only want one `['title'] ['description']` etc in the new array but I want the information from both arrays in the new array

Comment: why not update your question with desired result?

Comment: @Jenny ...but which array do you want to take `title` and `description` from?

Comment: I believe the OP is looking for `array( 'title' => array(), 'description' => array());`

Comment: FYI, your update doesn't help describe your desired results, since an array can have one **and only one** `title` key.

Comment: @nickb I was attempting to explain things more clearly. I am attempting to implement your suggested solution now, thanks :)

Comment: @Jenny Not a problem, I hope it is what you are looking for, I am still not 100% what your desired output is but at least it's a starting point.

Comment: @nickb if you can imagine that I have two arrays, each with a list of documents..for example , a list of Books..containing:..titles, descriptions etc... I want to join these two lists (arrays) into one big list.

Comment: @Jenny - Do you have to join them, or do you just need to iterate over them? Because I'm sure there's a solution for iterating over both arrays as if they were one big array. But I think you should show an actual `print_r()` of those arrays, because you can't have multiple `title` or `description` keys in one array.

Comment: @nickb the way my application is at the moment, I need to join them. However if this is not possible I was thinking it may be possible for me to get away with using an array of arrays... I need to check this! Very hard work for a newbie like me!! :)

Answer (score 3):

I have found using array_replace_recursive nested works. This first call creates an array merged which may have some values removed, the second call will remerge back into your master array keeping all array keys from the master array but allowing the merged in array to overwrite values in the master.

```
 $mergedArray = array_replace_recursive($array2, array_replace_recursive($array1, $array2));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would merge all the keys, then merge the arrays, like so:

```
$merged = array();
foreach( array_merge( array_keys( $array1), array_keys( $array2)) as $key) {
    $values = array();
    if( array_key_exists( $key, $array1)) {
        $values[] = $array1[$key];
    }
    if( array_key_exists( $key, $array2)) {
        $values[] = $array2[$key];
    }
    $merged[$key] = $values;
}
```

You can see from [this demo](http://viper-7.com/hxaO6v) that this creates an array like:

```
Array
(
    [title] => Array
        (
            [0] => title1
            [1] => title2
        )

    [description] => Array
        (
            [0] => desc1
            [1] => desc2
        )

    [random information] => Array
        (
            [0] => random2
        )

)
```

Comment: I have tried this, It seems to be merging them inappropriately.. Lets say `$array1['title']` contained `'document1', 'document2'` and `$array2['title']` contained `'document3' and 'document4'`....now `$array3['title']` now contains the following list: `'document1'` then `'document3'` then `'document2'` then `'document4'`...my data is alot more complicated than this, but this is me simplifying it as best I can.. It is bedtime in my part of the world, I will attempt again tomorrow! Thanks! :)